# Outlook VBA oItem_ReplyAll stops triggering after an email draft is cancelled

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am using the following code to input the name of an attachment in the text of the email I am replying to.

I use two near-identical scripts to handle Reply and Reply all. When I boot outlook they work fine, but sometime later they will fail. I can reproduce the failure by replying to an email and then cancelling the send.

If I send the email then the script works perfectly ad infinitum until I exit an email window instead of pressing send.

What is it about cancelling a send that causes the script to stop being called?

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents oExpl As Explorer
Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem
Private bDiscardEvents, Cancel As Boolean
Private strAtt, FinalMsg As String
Private oAtt As Attachment
Private oResponse As MailItem

' Reply All
Private Sub oItem_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)


Dim FinalMsg As String
Dim olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim olDocument As Word.Document
Dim olSelection As Word.Selection

If bDiscardEvents = True Or oItem.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
       Exit Sub
End If

Cancel = True
bDiscardEvents = True
strAtt = ""

Call GoodExtensions 'Detect extensions to be included and put them into strAtt

If strAtt = "" Then Exit Sub 'quit if there are no attachments
FinalMsg = "Attached" & ": " & strAtt

    Set oResponse = oItem.ReplyAll
    oResponse.Display
    If oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Then oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 'prevent plaintext emails causing problems

    Set olInspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set olDocument = olInspector.WordEditor
    Set olSelection = olDocument.Application.Selection


 'Find the beginning of the email being replied to
With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application
    .Selection.WholeStory
    .Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With .Selection.Find
        .Text = "Subject:"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .Execute
    End With

    Dim SubjectFont As String 'capture formatting details from the "From:" text to allow blending
    Dim SubjectSize As Integer
    SubjectFont = .Selection.Font.Name
    SubjectSize = .Selection.Font.Size

    .Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    .Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    .Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    If InStr(.Selection.Text, "mportance") <> 0 Then
    .Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    End If

End With

'Insert the message and format it to blend in
olSelection.InsertBefore FinalMsg
olSelection.Font.Name = SubjectFont
olSelection.Font.Size = SubjectSize
olSelection.Font.Color = wdColorBlack
olSelection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
olSelection.TypeParagraph

'Embolden the word "Attached:" to ensure formatting compatibilty
With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application
    .Selection.WholeStory
    .Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With .Selection.Find
        .Text = "Attached:"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .Execute
    End With

.Selection.Font.Bold = True
End With

bDiscardEvents = False
Set oItem = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get the oItem object in the code?  Do you call the ReplyAll or click the corresponding button in the UI?

Comment: I click the "reply" or "reply all" button in the UI

Comment: Where is the declaration of `bDiscardEvents`? If this is a module- or public-scoped variable and it's `True`, then this procedure **will** run, but it will take the first `Exit Sub`

Comment: I added in the declarations. Adding `Exit Sub` at the end seemed to fix it but then it broke again after I did some stuff.

Comment: I still didn't get any information where you get the olItem object in the code. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry I think that is because I don't understand where one "gets" something like this. That line of code was donated to me and it's not something I'm fully familiar with. Can you give me an idea of what I should search to learn about this? Thanks

Comment: See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: A little less specific than I was hoping for. I'll take the hint though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of the boolean `bDiscardEvents` - in particular its use in the test

```
If bDiscardEvents = True Or oItem.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
       Exit Sub
End If
```

Its use here leads to the subroutine always exiting prematurely if it is called after an exit from the routine before setting it `false` e.g. after `If strAtt = "" Then Exit Sub` has triggered.  The boolean is not required and can be removed.

The diagnosis is that this boolean has been used in some of Diane Poremsky's macros ([www.slipstick.com](https://www.slipstick.com)/), which I'm sure your code inherits from. However here its not required. She herself replied on being queried about its use in a similar function to yours says

> "In this version of the macro, it looks like its not doing anything...
> in the original macro, it was used much like cancel. When the macro
> was edited for this example, it wasn't removed. :("

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain the true origin of the problem, even after 5 years!

Comment: You're welcome! As you may have guessed, I had much the same problem with some VBA code I was trying to get working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like setting the oItem to nothing at the end was what was causing problems. I can no longer replicate the problem with this line removed. My code is below.

```
' Reply All
Private Sub oItem_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)


Dim FinalMsg As String
Dim olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim olDocument As Word.Document
Dim olSelection As Word.Selection

If bDiscardEvents Or oItem.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
       Exit Sub
End If

Cancel = True
bDiscardEvents = True
strAtt = ""

Call GoodExtensions 'Detect extensions to be included and put them into strAtt

If strAtt = "" Then Exit Sub 'quit if there are no attachments
FinalMsg = "Attached" & ": " & strAtt

    Set oResponse = oItem.ReplyAll
    oResponse.Display
    If oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Then oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 'prevent plaintext emails causing problems

    Set olInspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set olDocument = olInspector.WordEditor
    Set olSelection = olDocument.Application.Selection


 'Find the beginning of the email being replied to
With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application
    .Selection.WholeStory
    .Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With .Selection.Find
        .Text = "Subject:"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .Execute
    End With
    'capture formatting details from the "From:" text to allow blending
    Dim SubjectFont As String
    Dim SubjectSize As Integer
    Dim SubjectBold As Boolean
    SubjectFont = .Selection.Font.Name
    SubjectSize = .Selection.Font.Size
    SubjectBold = .Selection.Font.Bold

    .Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    .Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    .Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    If InStr(.Selection.Text, "mportance") <> 0 Then
    .Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    End If

End With

'Insert the message and format it to blend in
olSelection.InsertBefore FinalMsg
olSelection.Font.Name = SubjectFont
olSelection.Font.Size = SubjectSize
olSelection.Font.Color = wdColorBlack
olSelection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
olSelection.TypeParagraph

'Embolden the word "Attached:" if necessary to ensure formatting compatibility
With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application
    .Selection.WholeStory
    .Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With .Selection.Find
        .Text = "Attached:"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .Execute
    End With

.Selection.Font.Bold = SubjectBold
End With

bDiscardEvents = False
'Set oItem = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was still having the problem but the code now appears to work perfectly since removing the bdiscardevents criteria - I never diagnosed what this was even supposed to do.

I have pasted my entire ThisOutlookSession because it is only used for attachment detection and is intertwined in a way I am not confident to unravel. I would welcome any feedback.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents oExpl As Explorer
Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem
Private bDiscardEvents, Cancel As Boolean
Private strAtt, FinalMsg As String
Private oAtt As Attachment
Private oResponse As MailItem

 Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
   bDiscardEvents = False
End Sub

Private Sub oExpl_SelectionChange()
   On Error Resume Next
   Set oItem = oExpl.Selection.item(1)
End Sub

' Reply
Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' This adds the name of any attachments   '
' in an email to the reply of said email. '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'Dim finalmsg As String
Dim olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim olDocument As Word.Document
Dim olSelection As Word.Selection

If oItem.Attachments.Count = 0 Then 
       Exit Sub
End If

Cancel = True
bDiscardEvents = True

Call GoodExtensions

If strAtt = "" Then Exit Sub
FinalMsg = "Attached" & ": " & strAtt


Set oResponse = oItem.Reply
oResponse.Display
If oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Then oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 'prevent plaintext emails causing problems


Call insertAttachmentList

bDiscardEvents = False
'Set oItem = Nothing

End Sub
' Reply All
Private Sub oItem_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' This adds the name of any attachments   '
' in an email to the reply of said email. '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim olDocument As Word.Document
Dim olSelection As Word.Selection

If oItem.Attachments.Count = 0 then Exit Sub

Cancel = True
bDiscardEvents = True

Call GoodExtensions 'Detect extensions to be included and put them into strAtt

If strAtt = "" Then Exit Sub 'quit if there are no attachments
FinalMsg = "Attached" & ": " & strAtt

    Set oResponse = oItem.ReplyAll
    oResponse.Display
    If oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Then oResponse.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 'prevent plaintext emails causing problems


Call insertAttachmentList

bDiscardEvents = False
'Set oItem = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
Sub insertAttachmentList()

 'Find the beginning of the email being replied to
With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application
    .Selection.WholeStory
    .Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With .Selection.Find
        .Text = "Subject:"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .Execute
    End With
    If Not InStr(.Selection.Text, "ubject") <> 0 Then
        msg = MsgBox("Subject line not found. Abort", vbCritical)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'capture formatting details from the "From:" text to allow blending
    Dim SubjectFont As String
    Dim SubjectSize As Integer
    Dim SubjectBold As Boolean
    SubjectFont = .Selection.Font.Name
    SubjectSize = .Selection.Font.Size
    SubjectBold = .Selection.Font.Bold

    .Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    .Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    .Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    If InStr(.Selection.Text, "mportance") <> 0 Then
    .Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    End If

End With

'Insert the message and format it to blend in
With Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection
    .InsertBefore FinalMsg
    .Font.Name = SubjectFont
    .Font.Size = SubjectSize
    .Font.Color = wdColorBlack
    .EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    .TypeParagraph
End With

'Embolden the word "Attached:" if necessary to ensure formatting compatibility
With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application
    .Selection.WholeStory
    .Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With .Selection.Find
        .Text = "Attached:"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .Execute
    End With

.Selection.Font.Bold = SubjectBold
End With
MsgBox "Attachment text added"
End Sub


Sub GoodExtensions()
Dim AttachName As String
FinalMsg = ""
strAtt = ""
For Each oAtt In oItem.Attachments
AttachName = LCase(oAtt.FileName)
    If InStr(LCase(AttachName), "pdf") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "xls") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "doc") <> 0 _
            Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "ppt") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "msg") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "mac") <> 0 _
            Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "arc") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "prj") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "rsl") <> 0 _
            Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "results") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "screenshot") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "vtc") <> 0 _
            Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "BLANK_PARAMETER") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "BLANK_PARAMETER") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "BLANK_PARAMETER") <> 0 _
            Or oAtt.Size > 95200 Then
            strAtt = strAtt & "<" & oAtt.FileName & ">, "
    End If
Next oAtt

End Sub
'This sub inserts the name of any meaningful attachments just after the signature
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim oAtt As Attachment
Dim strAtt, DateMark, ShortTime, FinalMsg, AttachName, TriggerText  As String
Dim olInspector, oInspector As Inspector
Dim olDocument, olSelection As Object
Dim NewMail As MailItem
Dim AttchCount, i As Integer
strAtt = ""
FinalMsg = ""
'Stop
TriggerText = "Company Registration 1702660" 'This must be the last line of your signature or other place you want to insert the attachment text. It needs to be present in every email.

If TypeOf item Is MailItem Then Set NewMail = item
If item.Class = olMeetingRequest Then Exit Sub

With NewMail
    AttchCount = .Attachments.Count

    If AttchCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To AttchCount
        AttachName = .Attachments.item(i).DisplayName
            If InStr(LCase(AttachName), "pdf") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "xls") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "doc") <> 0 _
            Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "ppt") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "msg") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "mac") <> 0 _
            Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "arc") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "prj") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "rsl") <> 0 _
            Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "results") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "screenshot") <> 0 Or InStr(LCase(AttachName), "BLANK_PARAMETER") <> 0 _
            Or .Attachments.item(i).Size > 95200 Then
                strAtt = strAtt & "[" & AttachName & "] " & "<br/>"
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End With

' this section is an alternative method of getting attachment names
'For Each oAtt In Item.Attachments
'    If InStr(oAtt.FileName, "xls") <> 0 Or InStr(oAtt.FileName, "doc") <> 0 Or InStr(oAtt.FileName, "pdf") <> 0 Or InStr(oAtt.FileName, "ppt") <> 0 Or InStr(oAtt.FileName, "msg") <> 0 Or oAtt.Size > 95200 Then
'    strAtt = strAtt & "<<" & oAtt.FileName & ">> " & vbNewLine
'End If
'Next
'Set olInspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
'Set olDocument = olInspector.WordEditor
'Set olSelection = olDocument.Application.Selection

DateMark = "" '" (dated " & Date & ")" 'Not necessary when sub works well
If strAtt = "" Then 'Reduce risk of erroneous entries.
    FinalMsg = ""
    'Exit Sub
Else
    FinalMsg = "<br/><br/>" & "Files attached to this email" & DateMark & ":<br/>" & vbNewLine & strAtt
End If

Dim inputArea, SearchTerm As String
Dim SignatureLine, FromLine, EndOfEmail As Integer

If Not item.BodyFormat = 2 Then item.BodyFormat = 2 'force use of html
item.HTMLBody = Replace(item.HTMLBody, TriggerText & ".", TriggerText & FinalMsg)
If Not FinalMsg = "" Then MsgBox Replace(FinalMsg, "<br/>", vbNewLine)
'Stop
Exit Sub
```